High pass filter with narrow stop band and low group delay over part of passband
Consider the following filtering requirements for a nominally high pass IIR or FIR filter (assume a sample rate of $F_s =1$):
Stopband: $f\in[0, 0.00144]$ -- looking for around 20dB attenuation
Passband: $f\in[0.00192, 0.0096]$ -- 1.5dB ripple allowed but strict group delay requirements (< 5 samples, group delay variation is OK).
Loose requirements band: $f\in[0.0192, 0.5]$  -- group delay irrelevant, magnitude response should be less than +3dB (attenuation beneath 0dB is fine).
IIR Filter order: numerator and denominator should be less than around 6th order.
I'd consider a "low order" FIR filter (15-20 taps) as well.
What makes this filter challenging is the tight group delay requirement close to the stopband.  Standard designs fail.  Matlab's arbitrary magnitude and phase least squares designer produces unstable IIR filters (poles outside the unit circle).
I thought about decimating, filtering, and interpolating, but the low rate filtering problem didn't seem easier from a group delay perspective.  The sample rate changes will also introduce delay.
Is this a realistic ask?  What's my best approach?

I'm by far not as used to IIR design as to FIR design, and even there I'd call myself "little more than an amateur", compared to the rest of this community, but, the critical parameter for the group delay will be the steepness of the stopband-passband transition. And at less than 1/1000 of the Nyquist rate that is a narrow transition. As said, I'm no expert in IIR design – but maybe the others have a grand idea what to approach more relaxed, or completely differently, when you add information on where that intense set of requirements arises from.

I'd consider a low(ish) order FIR filter as well (say 15 or 20 taps).  But, I agree, this is a hard (maybe impossible) filtering problem.   I was hoping that the relatively large band above 0.0192 with looser requirements could help make this doable.

I don't think this can be done.
Preamble: I did the analysis at a sample rate of 48 kHz (since this is more intuitive to an audio person). This moves the stop band to 69 Hz and the pass band to 92Hz-460Hz.
Linear phase FIR filters are out since the group delay spec limits the filter length to 11 taps. 11 taps at 48 kHz is only about $230 \mu s$. That's not enough to have any significant impact in the 80 Hz range. As a rule of thumb, the impulse response length needs to be in the order of the inverse of the lowest frequency where there is a non-trivial slope which would be around 600 in this case.
So the obvious choice is a minimum phase filter. I tried an IIR filter and it turns out that a 3rd order elliptic filter will meet the amplitude specification.

However the group delay close to the steep slope is quite large and exceeds over 600 samples in the pass band. Incidentally, this matches well with our "rule of thumb" above.


I was hoping that the relatively large band above 0.0192 with looser requirements could help make this doable.

Not really. Keep in mind that the minimum phase and the log magnitude of the transfer function are related by the Hilbert Transform which contains a weighting factor of $\frac{1}{\Delta f}$. This means that it's inversely proportional to the distance in frequency. The frequencies above the pass band are simply too far away from the problem region to have much of an impact. Also "flattish" regions of the magnitude don't move the phase much. By creatively shuffling things around you may be able to knock down the group delay by a factor of 2, but you are off by more than a 100.
The main problem here is the extremely steep slope which is more than $6600 \frac{\text{dB}}{\text{rad}}$. The gradient is enormous and so will be the group delay.

After listening to DSP Related Conference Presentations by fred harris over the past few years, he seems adamant that in your type of situation (whereby both stop and pass-bands as well as the transition band are fractions of the fs), the sampling rate should first be lowered before processing. This would lower that relative filter design constraints considerably.  Also, if you switch to a symmetric FIR, you can rely on linear phase thereby solving the group delay problem. True, you will have to acquiesce to the additional delay involved, but it didn't seem for your description that this was a major constraint.

Sorry, this won't work. It's quite difficult to downsample without adding group delay. Even if you can, that also down-samples your group delay requirement. If you down-sample by a factor of 5, the  max group delay becomes 1 sample at the lower sample rate. You can't do much with that. Same of linear phase filter. If you have a max group delay of 5 samples, the max length of any linear phase filter will 11 samples. That's not enough.
