Phase equalization for a notch-like filter
Consider the following filter with DC-notch-like characteristics:
$H(z) = \frac{1-2z^{-1} + z^{-2}}{1+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2}}$
where $a_1= -1.99396970948671$ and $a_2=0.994002716421032$.
The magnitude and phase response are shown below:

I would like to equalize the phase of this filter over a band close to DC: $f\in F=[0.0019, 0.019]$ where the Nyquist frequency is normalized to one.  Excess group delay is undesirable in the phase equalizer.  Ideally, the combined phase response over the band-of-interest $F$ should be close to zero (or retain the linear phase of the numerator), but I don't know how realistic such a requirement is.  While, the numerator produces a group delay of one sample, that's not a big deal.  The problem is the irregular phase response of the denominator over $F$.
A strictly all-pass phase equalizer is not required.  Some degree of magnitude squared variation can be tolerated (on the order of a dB or two) over $F$.
I tried FIR designs based on least squares, which were terrible.  I tried using
this code, but it doesn't run (appears to have been written for a very old version of matlab, and also appears to simply contains bugs that cause it to crash).  I tried matlab's fdesign.arbmagnphase with iirls, but it only produces unstable filters.
Can anyone propose an equalization filter that would meet my needs?

That seems like a duplicate of your other question. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/94520/high-pass-filter-with-narrow-stop-band-and-low-group-delay-over-part-of-passband . In any case, the same answer applies. You can't flatten this out without incurring a sizable chunk of group delay (many hundreds of samples).

If all you need as a DC blocker: there are ways of doing this without a high pass filter.

@Hilmar Would such a DC blocker have controllable notch width?  What specifically did you have in mind?

Yes, I'll delete this question as it's very similar to my previous question.

I have a suggestion but it would help if you put a bound on what "excess group delay" would still be acceptable vs terrible; there will be a trade between group delay variation and overall delay that may open up different approaches.

@DanBoschen -- on the order of around 5 samples over the band F would be barely acceptable.
